# Помогите пожалуйста с циклом в python

Tags: python

В общем, баланс выводит не тот. Нужна переменная `player`, которая в первом цикле, как ее во второй запихать я не понял? Там где `player.balance(`

```
if cmd.lower() in ("топ", ):
    Player = self.player
    #Получаем игроков из база данных с наивысшим балансом в кол-ве 15 штук.
    Player = await self.pwmanager.execute(Player.select().order_by(Player.balance.desc()).limit(10))

    text = " Самые богатые в казино « Seven Dragons »  \n"
    
    users = []
    
    for player in Player:
        users.append(str(player.user_id))

    pikachu = await self.api.users.get(user_ids=','.join(users))
    #Выводим что получилось
    for i, user in enumerate(pikachu):
        text += (
            str(i + 1) + f".  @id{user['id']} (" + user['first_name'] + " " + user['last_name'] + ") ➡ "
            + "{:,}".format(player.balance).replace(",", ".") + "\n"
        )

    self.current.remove(msg.user_id)

    return await msg.answer(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сохраните значение в мапу в первом цикле. что-то вроде

```
    user_balance_map = {}    
    for player in Player:
        users.append(str(player.user_id))
        user_balance_map[player.user_id] = player.balance

    pikachu = await self.api.users.get(user_ids=','.join(users))
    #Выводим что получилось
    for i, user in enumerate(pikachu):
        text += (
            str(i + 1) + f".  @id{user['id']} (" + user['first_name'] + " " + user['last_name'] + ") ➡ "
            + "{:,}".format(user_balance_map[user['id']]).replace(",", ".") + "\n"
        )
```

Comment: баланс имеет decimal значение ничего страшного?

Comment: Все заработало, огромное вам спасибо)